# Conjugate of a Wavefunction

Tags: complex, algebraic-manipulation

I haven't seen much on this topic, but that's probably because - for superpositions of only a few quantum states - it can be done by inspection rather than Mathematica.

Still, I would like to know how to compute the conjugate of a wavefunction, and I am having trouble getting Mathematica to do this.

My wavefunction is:

```
Ψ = b1*Exp[-I*ω1*t]*ψ1 + b2*Exp[-I*ω1*t]*Exp[-I*ω*t]*ψ2
```

Which I then try to take the conjugate of:

```
Simplify[Conjugate[Ψ], t ω1 ω ∈ Reals]
```

But Mathematica just outputs the following:

```
E^(I Conjugate[t ω1])Conjugate[b1 ψ1 + b2 E^(-I t ω) ψ2]
```

Ideally, I'd like it so that it doesn't just say 'Conjugate', and then leave all of the expressions as they were. In texts, you would see complexes denoted by an '*' in superscript. Is there any way to see this also by a Conjugate function in Mathematica?

Comment: In Mathematica imaginary unit is `I` not `i`!

Comment: Oh what a rookie error. Thank you - fixed the i's but doesn't affect Mathematica's ability to perform the conjugate sadly.

Comment: See my answer, `ComplexExpand`might help.

Answer (score 2):

Change `i` to `I`

```
Ψ = b1*Exp[-I*ω1*t]*ψ1 + b2*Exp[-I*ω1*t]*Exp[-I*ω*t]*ψ2

Simplify[Conjugate[Ψ],Element[{t, ω1, ω}, Reals]]
(*E^(I t ω1) Conjugate[b1 ψ1 + b2 E^(-I t ω) ψ2]*)
```

Further Simplification might be achieved with `ComplexExpand`

```
ComplexExpand[Conjugate[Ψ]]
(*b1 ψ1 Cos[t ω1] + b2 ψ2 Cos[t ω + t ω1] - 
I (-b1 ψ1 Sin[t ω1] -b2 ψ2 Sin[t ω + t ω1])*)
```

For complex `b1,b2` try

```
ComplexExpand[Conjugate[Ψ], {b1, b2}]
(*ψ1 (Cos[t ω1] Re[b1] + 
Im[b1] Sin[t ω1]) + ψ2 (Cos[ t ω + t ω1] Re[b2] + Im[b2] Sin[t ω + t ω1]) - 
I (ψ1 (Cos[t ω1] Im[b1] -Re[b1] Sin[t ω1]) + ψ2 (Cos[t ω + t ω1] Im[b2] -Re[b2] Sin[t ω + t ω1]))*)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info - your first answer is helpful, as it at least gives the \[Omega]1 exponential term conjugate. Is there any way that you know of where the conjugates of b1 and b2 can be shown as b1* and b2*, or is this not a Mathematica functionality?

Comment: Sorry don't know how to do that. But if you know `b1,b2`are complex, tell it `ComplexExpand`(see my modified answer)

Comment: `(Ψconj = Assuming[Element[{t, ω1, ω}, Reals], ComplexExpand[Conjugate[Ψ], {b1, b2}, TargetFunctions -> Conjugate] // Simplify]) // TraditionalForm`

Comment: @TubularHell Ulrich may be overthinking regarding how to achieve such formatting. Ulrich, you may simply add `//FullSimplify//TraditionalForm` to your last example to achieve OP’s desired form.